# Referencing TailwindCSS config from JavaScript in SvelteKit

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, vite, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit, which uses Vite and the setup instructions calls for CommonJS config files:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit

However, the guide for referencing the configuration in JavaScript requires ESM.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script

Attempting to change the `tailwind.config.cjs` to ESM doesn't work (I get errors from other libraries trying to `require()` it as CJS).

Does anyone know how I can either get a working ESM `tailwind.config.js` in SvelteKit or a different better method to reference the tailwind config?

Comment: I'm wanting the same. the maintainer of `svelte-add` will be implementing it soon hopefully. i think cjs was used because of postcss not handling esm..but they recently added it

https://github.com/svelte-add/svelte-add/issues/209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I restored to writing my definitions in a separate `.json` file.

I then import that into the Tailwind config file, and also import those definitions elsewhere where I need them (as `json`).

Answer (score 0):

[Since tailwind v3.3](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-3#esm-and-type-script-support) you can write your config file using ESM or Typescript.

```
npx tailwindcss init --esm
```

```
npx tailwindcss init --ts
```

I converted my config into ts, then I did

```
import tailwindConfig from '../../tailwind.config'; // Change path accordingly
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
const fullConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)
```

[Source example from the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script)